# Why is the emitter current of a common emitter slightly greater than the collector current?

Tags: electric-current, semiconductor-physics, electronics, electrical-engineering

I'm trying understand where electricians came to agreement that Ie = Ib + Ic. I know that the base of a NPN transistor is very thin, allowing electrons to flow through to the collector which explains why $I_{c} = \beta I_{b}$. Mathematically, I can also see that when we have $\alpha = \frac{I_{c}}{I_{e}} = \frac{\beta}{1+\beta}$ But I want to understand the actual physics behind this phenomenon, so that I could remember it for my E5 advancement exam.

Comment: $I_e=I_b+I_c$ is a statement of conservation of current.  The net current that leaves the transistor must equal the net current that enters it.

Comment: @garyp That seems like an answer, not a comment.

Comment: @Navy_Colors $I_E=I_B+I_C$ is the Kirchoff's current law applied at the node of the transistor. Please look at the Ebers Moll model for better understnding

Answer (score 0):

Charge conservation.

Emitter **emit**s electrons and collector **collect** the electrons. When emitted electron goes into base region which is p type material (for npn transistor) this electron have a nonzero probability to recombine. However, after recombination charge neutral base becomes negative charged and pull **hole** from the base. This mechanism is one of the component of base current.

Think like you have **5** electron in emitter and you emit through them to collector. In the base this electrons have **%20** recombination probability. You will lose one electron at the base and pull **one hole** to base to preserve charge neutrality. At the end you have **4** electron at collector side.

$$I_E = I_B+I_C$$